# AngularJs input url into iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I am trying to have the user input a youtube url,
and have that url show up on the iframe.
but the video does not seem to show.

I added the angular html code:

```
<html ng-app>
```

The iframe script:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="동영상 URL..">
 <iframe height="180" width="310" src="{{yourName}}"></iframe>
```

Typing in "asd"
shows the error:
HTTP Status 404 - /Test1/WireFrame2/asd

Comment: Why would you type "asd" ? Aren't you expecting an absolute URL ?

Comment: asd was just to check if the angularJs was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the user needs to input the youtube URL typing `asd` will show error because it will look for a relative URL, hence you see `/Test1/WireFrame2/asd`.

YouTube links require `/embed/` if you want to include them as a src for iframe.

For instance, for a link `www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz` you'll need `www.youtube.com/embed/xyz` so you will have to format the input.

Once you do all that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried inserting embed

www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k shows the error
HTTP Status 404 - /Test1/WireFrame2/www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k

http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k
shows a blank screen.

Comment: @user3509211 `/Test1/WireFrame2/www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k` is a relative URL. Try inserting `http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k`

Comment: adding the http
   http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k 
shows a blank screen in the iframe. no error. no video.

Comment: @user3509211 `http://www.youtube.com/XGSy3_Czz8k` just as a url, shows 404. That means that video does not exist. Take `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGdGFtwCNBE` for instance. Make sure you can see it in a browser, then try with `/embed/` and try hard coding `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gGdGFtwCNBE`. Notice you only need what's after the `v=`